# I have a question about JSON PHP Multi Values

Tags: php, json

I want to select the database more values (I already did) and be converted to JSON

I tried all

php

```
$a = $_GET['name'];

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo '{"results":[';
$selectSearch = "SELECT * from `users` WHERE `name` LIKE '".$a["term"]."%'";
$rezultatul = $db->query($selectSearch);
if ($rezultatul->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $rezultatul->fetch_assoc()) {
        $name = $row["name"];

        $arr = array('id' => $row["id"], 'text' => $row["name"], 'level' => $row["Level"]);
        echo json_encode($arr);
    }
}


echo ']}';
```

And he looks like this:

```
{"results":[{"id":"1","text":"Pompiliu","level":"7"}
{"id":"11","text":"Pompiliu1","level":"100"}]}
```

But between the two must be like that

```
{"id":"1","text":"Pompiliu","level":"7"}, 
{"id":"11","text":"Pompiliu1","level":"100"}
```

And when there will be 3 results

```
{"id":"1","text":"Pompiliu","level":"7"},
{"id":"11","text":"Pompiliu1","level":"100"},
{"id":"12","text":"Pompiliu2","level":"100"}
```

Comment: I don't get it, what you are getting is json data? So how is this wrong?

Comment: The comma does not count between those tables

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ to [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) attacks. Look into using [prepared statements with placeholders](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries.

Comment: @Mark_Ed - They get invalid json data since there's no comma between the objects in the array.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson to be fair, that was hard to spot in the original revision of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Add to the array with `[]` and then json_encode.
Don't try and build json strings on your own.

```
if ($rezultatul->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $rezultatul->fetch_assoc()) {
        $name = $row["name"];

        $arr[] = array('id' => $row["id"], 'text' => $row["name"], 'level' => $row["Level"]);
    }
}
echo json_encode(["results" => $arr]);
```